# searching ArrayList with multiple data types

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Ive got an ArrayList with `String`, `int` and `double` in it, a total of 20 elements.

Im trying to move the `Strings` to a String-array, the `ints` to an int-array and the `doubles` to a double-array. But I cant figure out how, this is what I have for fnding Integers:

```
    private ArrayList <Object> randomList = new ArrayList <Object>();
    private int [] intArray = new int[10];

    public void example(){
    createArray();
    for(int i = 0; i<randomList.size();i++){
        if(randomList.get(i)instanceof Integer){
            intArray[i]= (Integer) randomList.get(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I cant understand why this dosnt work, it tries to add objects that arent Integers into my array causing an outOfBounds exception, since its trying to add more then 10 elements.

Comment: Mixing different types in the same list is a code smell.  Why do you want that in the first place?

Comment: cus I was bored and annoyed that I couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have index mismatch, that's all. Try something like:

```
int index = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<randomList.size();i++)
{
        if(randomList.get(i)instanceof Integer)
        {
            intArray[index++]= (Integer) randomList.get(i);
        }
}
```

You should also check whether the current index for a particular array is less than the upper boundary, which is the initial size of that array:

```
if(randomList.get(i) instanceof Integer && index < intArray.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a separate index into each of your output arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you should never have allowed all these data types to congregate in on ArrayList of objects. But if you already have them:

```
for(Object o : randomList)
{
    if(o instanceof Integer)
    {
        //add to inteeger list
    }
    else if(o intenaceof String)
    {
       //add to string list
    }
    //...etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try initializing your array as :

   ```
   private int [] intArray = new int[randomList.size()];
   ```
2. Try another index to assign values to array:

   ```
   int count=0;
   for(int i = 0; i<randomList.size();i++){
       if(randomList.get(i)instanceof Integer){
          intArray[count++] = (Integer) randomList.get(i);
       }
   }
   ```
3. In the end, you may want to truncate the array fragment which was unused using  `System.arraycopy` as below:

   ```
   private int [] finalArray= new int[count;
   System.arraycopy(intArray, 0, finalArray, 0, count);
   ```

Comment: @MrCharli3L Just be careful of the situations when you have more that 10 integers in your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int [] intArray = new int[10];
```

Your array has a size of 10, but your list does not have a size limit.

```
private int [] intArray = new int[randomList.size()];
```

might work.